# Chrome computes 1px as 6px, messes up styles that use rem

Tags: css, google-chrome

The website has font-size for  set like this:

```
html {
    font-size: 1px;
}
```

But Chrome computes it as 6px and messes up all other styles that use rem sizing.

I didn't actually have this problem before, until I had to change minimum size of font in Chrome. Then I restored the settings but the problem persisted. (I also tried to reinstall the browser even but to no avail)
It doesn't happen in other browsers, doesn't happen in Chrome browsers on other devices, so I guess it has to do with me changing the minimum size of the font.

Any ideas how can I fix this? I guess Chrome sets minimum font-size as 1px by default but now I messed it up with user settings?

Comment: Try this: 

html, body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none
}

Comment: The problem is: I get this problem on any website that uses rem sizes. I need to fix my browser, not css styles.

Comment: I believe the minimum font-size set by chrome is 10px so getting 6px is odd. Setting font-size to 10px and adjusting your rem declaration by a factor of 10 should solve it.

Comment: I'm seeing this too. -wekit-text-size-adjust doesn't seem to work.